# html5 video tag + flash video: how to change priority

Tags: html, html5-video, flash-video

i'm playing around with html5 video cause it's nice to have fallback for iphone/ipad. 
html5 video first checks for `<source>` elements, if no formats are supported it falls back to whatever content is provided inside the `<video>` tag (e.g. flash).

i'd love to reverse the behaviour to save bandwidth: use flash by default, if not available fall back to html5 video.

is there *any* way to get this behaviour without using javascript? (then the solution gets quite obvious).

best, hansi,-

p.s. i did try turning the elements "inside-out" (`<object><video/></object>` instead of `<video><object/></video>`, but that results the video displayed twice)

p.p.s. my current solution is

```
if( navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"] ){ ... }
else{ ... }
```

which is sub-optimal, cause it works for iphone/ipad, but results in a big mess when using old browsers without flash installed.

Comment: Did you include type="application/x-shockwave-flash" in your <object> tag? For example, <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="384" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.SWF"><video /></object>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks "zach at longtail"!, that worked!

for reference, here's how to get the "flash first, then html5" behaviour:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="..." height="..." data="...">
    <param name="movie" value="..." />
    <video width="..." height="...">
        <source src="..." type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="..." type="video/webm" />
        <source src="..." type="video/ogg" />
    </video>
</object>
```

**For providing html5-alternatives to youtube/vimeo embeds:** 
Please note that having the `<object data="..." />` attribute is crucial and that it is missing in the embedding code that youtube/vimeo/etc. provide. 
Make sure to change that, just throwing the `<video/>` tag in the code you copy+pasted will give you exactly the headache i had.